# Replace text link with image: CSS problem

Tags: css

I'm using Technique #8 from [Nine Techniques for CSS Image Replacement](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/) but I'm not seeing the results I expect: instead of nicely positioned images, I'm getting... well, look for yourself:

http://beatchamber.officemedic.net

One change I've made to the technique is to change all the width: 100%/height: 100% values to the actual sizes; without that the images didn't display at all. I'm baffled, however, as to why the technique isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: what you have tried post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because your background images are larger than the space you want to put them in. Also, your background images have a fair amount of "padding" on the outside of them, lending to that strange spacing where the text starts. If you added more height/width to your list elements, or changed the padding, you could get them looking like you want them to. As-is, though, they get cut off by the 25px/75px width/height.

Comment: Hmm. Well, no, the height and width of the list item elements is set to the size of the images. I think I've fixed the issue, though, by setting the list item elements to display: inline-block instead of display: inline. Firebug is now indicating that the position is correct, whereas before there was an offset. I think that was the "padding" you were seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Its working demo here text is replace by Image using CSS code

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wcmjt/)